# Select selenium element by name with parantheses?

Tags: unit-testing, firefox, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I have the following input element:

`<input name='selected(1234)' type="checkbox" />`

When I record, I get this:

```
Command: click
Target: selected(1234)
```

This doesn't find the element, and neither does

`Target: name=selected(1234)`

My assumption is that the parentheses are somehow messing with the lookup. What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Also, I should note that the default recorded value works after being recorded, but when input manually or run through an RC test, it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a timing issue. If you record a test in selenium-IDE, it won't give you the `waitForPageLoad` commands you need when you convert the test to java.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an XPath:

```
Command: click
Target: xpath=//input[@type='checkbox'][@name='selected(1234)']
```

However, if you're trying to check (as in mark not verify) the checkbox, you really should use:

```
Command: check
Target: xpath=//input[@type='checkbox'][@name='selected(1234)']
```

Comment: Wait a second, why are you trying to click on the checkbox? Are you simply trying to check it or are you trying to trigger the onclick event?

Comment: ...this is a selenium-RC test. Of course I'm actually trying to click it.

Comment: I mean, are you trying to check\uncheck the checkbox?

Comment: Using Selenium RC and Python this works and so does name=selected(1234). Are you working in the right frame? Can you tell us the exact error that you are getting.

Comment: Element not found, and there are no frames on the page.

Comment: I think you may be right about the parenthesis messing with the lookup. What about a locator that doesn't include parenthesis in the name like: `xpath=//input[@type='checkbox'][contains(@name, 'selected')][contains(@name, '1234')]`?